# iOS - UITableView shows wrong number of stars for cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, lazy-loading

I am using [AMRatingControl](https://github.com/amseddi/AMRatingControl) and I like it and first it looks everything ok but then I find out that it has some trouble in TableView. I am adding control to cell with this code:

```
AMRatingControl *coloredRatingControl = [[AMRatingControl alloc] initWithLocation:CGPointMake(136,59)
                                                                           emptyColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                           solidColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                         andMaxRating:5];
    [coloredRatingControl setRating:(NSInteger)([place.Rating integerValue] / 2.0)];
    [coloredRatingControl setEnabled:NO];
    //[coloredRatingControl setNeedsDisplay];
    //[coloredRatingControl setNeedsLayout];
    [cell addSubview:coloredRatingControl];
```

I have it in method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    .....
```

For the first few cells it's okay and control is displayed fine but when you scroll then for later cells it showing wrong number of stars but in place.Rating there is right number. I set break point and code and values look fine. Maybe it's something with lazy loading and using this control but I don't know how to fix this. I find out that it depends on shown stars at few first rows. There is pattern. In my screen first 4 cells are shown and has right number of stars (5th cell is not shown but it has right number too) and then these 5 rating are repeating and 6th has same rating as 1st but it's wrong and same goes for 7th (has same as 2nd) and so. I set other things in cellForRowAtIndexPath like image and so and it's okay. It's just these rating controls. I tried to force some redraw with commented methods at first example code but it didn't help.

Comment: Please try this  UITableViewCell *cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; cell is reusing in the above case

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    AMRatingControl *coloredRatingControl;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        coloredRatingControl = [[AMRatingControl alloc] initWithLocation:CGPointMake(136,59)
                                                                       emptyColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                       solidColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                     andMaxRating:5];
         [coloredRatingControl setEnabled:NO];
         [coloredRatingControl setTag:8888];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:coloredRatingControl];

    }

    coloredRatingControl = (AMRatingControl *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:8888];
    [coloredRatingControl setRating:(NSInteger)([place.Rating integerValue] / 2.0)];
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for help but second answer which is now delete was right. I was trying your solution and it didn't add control to cell. It didn't get into if condition. I guess because I have Cell defined in Storyboard.

Comment: @LiborZapletal It didn't get into if condition since you are using storyboard. Are you using custom uitableview cells?